# VCSA 6.5 remove .log.stderr file perfcharts

Tags: vmware, vcenter

It seems that there is any error that is causing that the files vmware-perfcharts-runtime.log.stderr and vmware-perfcharts-runtime.log.stdout size are huge. While I find out the issue, is it safe to remove the files while vCenter is running?

[image]

They are in /storage/log/vmware/perfcharts/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any problem to delete log files. Anyway i would prefer to empty the file just using

```
echo > wmware-perfcharts-runtime.log.stderr
```